# How can I update the position of all sprites in a CCSpriteBatchNode?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccspritebatchnode

I have a `CCSpriteBatchNode` containing 30 sprites. I'd like to move all of the sprites some deltaX. How can I do this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in myBatchNode.children) 
    sprite.position = ccpAdd(sprite.Position, ccp(deltaX, 0.0));
```

While this works I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way that perhaps doesn't involve explicitly visiting each node in the batch node. Note that I don't want to move the batch node itself.

Comment: This code is fine. It's also not inefficient. It does the job and it's not doing crazy wild stuff that'll do anything noticeable to your framerate. Especially not with 30 sprites. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would not

```
myBatchNode.position.x += deltaX;
```

do the same for you ?

Comment: Yes that could work. However I'd prefer not to the move the batch node itself.